# the button does not exceute my js script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to display a catalog view of students with php. To be more precisely I have the web page in which I have used jQuery, Ajax to load some parts of the page. What I want to do is to to display a list of students like a catalog with their information in which every item of the list has included first name ,last name, username etc. Also, this item must contain a button. Once the button is clicked the list view should be dismissed and another view with full details of the students should be loaded in the same area.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
  $("#$data").bind('click', function(){



        window.alert("It works");   
                        }

  )}
);

    </script>
```

Here is the code in php:

```
$data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM perdoruesi WHERE id>2 ");



    while($db_field=mysql_fetch_array($data)){

            echo "<tr><td>";

            echo $db_field['emri']. " "; 
            echo $db_field['mbiemri']. " ";
            echo $db_field['username']. " ";
            echo $db_field['passw']. " ";
            $data = $db_field['username'];
            echo "<button id = '$data'>".$data."</button>";                   
         echo "</td></tr>";
          }
```

when I click the button I want to execute the script but it does nothing. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

in your javascript your PHP variable `$data` doesn't exist. If your javascript is in the same page and you absolutly want to bind on the `id`, you can add your variable with `echo`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php echo 'var id="'.$data.'"'; ?>
$(function(){
    $("#"+id).bind('click', function(){
        window.alert("It works");   
    }
)}
);
</script>
```

or you can add a class to your button:

PHP:

```
 echo '<button id = "'.$data.'" class="userBtn">'.$data.'</button>';
```

and bind on it:

```
$(".userBtn").bind('click', function(){

   var btn_id = $(this).attr('id');

   if(btn_id === 'bob' ) {
        bobFunction();
   }  else if (btn_id === 'john' ) {
        johnFunction();
   }
)}
```

Comment: I want to find out which button was clicked as I have several button and for each button is a different id. Depending of its id, not its class, I want to execute js code. Can I do this in php?

Comment: Then you must use a selector that targets _each_ of your buttons on its own to bind the event handler to them … would be much easier if you _would_ just give them a common class.

Comment: @CBroe can you show a piece of code how to do that because i do not understand what do you want to say in your comment

Comment: that's what i proposed, a common class for all your buttons